# Rewrite the url using htaccess in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to WordPress, creating the custom taxonomy for location in the my current URL

http://localhost/myproject/locations/us

i am need to change the URL like in that location place rename to my-project

i am trying to change the URL using Rewrite rule in ht-access file

RewriteRule    ^my-project/us?$    http://localhost/myproject/locations/us    [R=301,NC,L]

but its not working any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Custom .htaccess in WordPress site can bring unexpected results.

You may instead use WordPress' specific [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Edit: if you need to use .htaccess insert your rules *before* the WordPress' ones.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^my-project/us?$ http://localhost/myproject/locations/us [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is the final .htaccess code, i tested this solution [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be) and it works correctly.

If this solution didn't solve your case maybe there is a problem elsewhere.

Comment: its is ok @Professore but i need to change the .htaccess

Comment: It should work. If you write http://localhost/my-project/us you should see the response of http://localhost/myproject/locations/us. What you see instead?